# jQuery selector with variable

Tags: jquery, variables, jquery-selectors

I need to select all images whose filename contain a certain string (variable) using jQuery. I am using:
`var str='-out.';

$('img[src*='+str+']'). //do something`

It works but fires the following warning in Firefox: " Expected ']' to terminate attribute selector but found '.' " Would someone know how to avoid this warning ?

Thank You

Comment: please provide the source code and the warning that's being fired.

Comment: Could you show as the warning ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need double quotes or single around the attribute value.

Look at Jquery Docs for [attr*="value"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-contains-selector/) selector

like this:

```
$("img[src*='"+str+"']")
```

OR

```
$('img[src*="'+str+'"]')
```

Comment: Is in attribute selector specification (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-selectors/) that you will need the double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I try the following code and firefox doesn't fires any warning (it works as aspected)?

```
   var str=".png";
    $('img[src*='+str+']').each(function(){
      console.info(this.alt);
    });
```