# Show the element if it has a class whose name is tested

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got a class name after I clicked a element in the document. And then I want to select all elements that has this selected class. For example;

```
$('.tabs1 li a').hover(function(){

var clicked = $(this).attr("class");

// this doesnt work
$('a[class="clicked"]').css("display","block");

});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery selector with variable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4108845/jquery-selector-with-variable)

Comment: Note that elements can have more than one class - the class attribute/property can contain a list of class names separated by white space.

Comment: Is `class="clicked"` supposed to be the element clicked in the function? what exactly this function is supposed to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's true that the `class` attribute can have multiple values. Like others, I'm guessing to an extent what the poster wants, but this at least allows for multiple classes (and accounts for spaces). If the poster's wanting to isolate just one of the classes, maybe that's another question or subquestion:

```
$('.tabs1 li a').hover(function(){
    var clicked = $(this).attr("class");
    clicked = clicked.replace(/(\s)+/g, '.');
    // this should work
    $('a.' + clicked).css({"display":"block", "background": "green"});
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/szpJb/2/

Comment: Added the `background: green` so it's easier to see that something happens

Answer (score 3):

You can build a [class selector](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) from the class name:

```
var clicked = $(this).attr("class");
$("a." + clicked).css("display", "block");
```

Comment: `clicked` might be a string with several classes.

Comment: @Felix, indeed it can. Unfortunately, the questioner does not specify what should happen then. Should the matched links expose *all* or *any* of the classes? :)